# Twigpress: Can't pass variables to twig template

Tags: wordpress, twig

I am using Twigpress with Wordpress. According to the [Twigpress doc](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twigpress/other_notes), you can pass variables to the template with **twigpress_render_twig_template($vals = array(), $template = false, $echo = true)**.

I'm trying to pass variables to the template with the following code but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**single.php:**

```
$vals = array( 'foo' => 'bar' );
twigpress_render_twig_template($vals);
```

**single.twig:**

```
{{ vals.foo }} # Does not print anything #
{{ foo }} # Same #
{{ dump(vals) }} # Prints 'null' #
```

Please enlighten a n00b! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable debug in your twig setting.

This is how I do it for my Twig initialization. I put this in a separate file call `twig-init.php` and just `require_once` where i need to use twig.

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/blah/twig/templates');
$settings = array(
    'cache' => '/blah/twig/compiled',
    'debug' => true
);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $settings);

if ($settings['debug'])
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

When you dump it, you can just do `{{ dump() }}` to dump everything instead.

In addition, you may need to access your array value via the `_context`. Try to `{{ dump(_context['foo']) }}`

If you really want to access the variable via `vals`, you will have to do the following to your array:

```
$blah = array('vals' => array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Then `{{ vals.foo }}` will work.

See: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html